# bigger font in labeling and diagram going side to side

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I am building around my 1st question. In it, I presented a game summary. Now here is guess the move. The user must figure out Morphy's move.

Here's my code in two part. The first part is the main body. The 2nd part is the game date.

I like to fix the output. The font in the comment is very small. Can I get it bigger. And the moves going top to bottom, not side-to-side. Can it be done? Thank you for your suggestion and feedback.

Main body:

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=20]{scrreprt}
% This is a LaTeX file generated by Scid.
% You must have the skak, KOMAScript and pstricks packages installed to typeset this file.
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[LSB2,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc} % use fontenc before chessboard
\usepackage{skak, xskak,chessboard}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}

\newcommand\guessmymove{% this is the 1st macro TO PRINT OUT ALL THE COMMENTS
      \xskakloop{%
    \ifcsempty{Xskak.\xskakgetgame{gameid}.\xskakget{movenr}.\xskakget{player}.nag}
    {}
    {%
    \getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
   \chessboard[boardfontfamily=alphadia,
     boardfontencoding=LSBC4,
      normallboard, showmover=false, label=false, pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=red,
      markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,color=blue, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
      emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen},
      coloremph=true,
      whitefieldmaskcolor=yellow,blackfieldmaskcolor=yellow,emphfield=\xskakget{moveto},, 
  setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
      \xskakget{opennr}
      \xskakget{lan}
      \xskakget{nag}
      \par
      }}}

\xskakset{style=UF}
\fontsize{10pt}{14pt}\selectfont
\font\sachy=SkakNew-Diagram at 10pt
\newdimen\muj \muj=-0.32ex

\makeatletter
\xskaknewstyleitem[%
 whiteopen={.~},
 blackopen={.\,\space\ldots},
 beforewhite={},%\space,
 beforeblack=\space,%\space,
 afterwhite=,%\space,
 afterblack={\space\,},%\space,
 ]{styleD}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%********************* GUESS THE MOVE ***************************
\onecolumn\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{center}
\setfigstyle{\normalfont}%
\setboardfontcolors{blackfieldmask=gray!40}
\input{game2}
%this is the MACRO guessmymove
\end{center}
\end{multicols}%

\end{document}

Game data body

    \newchessgame
\noindent
\hidemoves{
1.e4 e5  \xskakcomment{guess?}
2.Nf3 d6 \xskakcomment{guess?Hint: attack the center } 
3.d4 Bg4 \xskakcomment{guess?} 
4.dxe5 Bxf3 \xskakcomment{guess?}
5.Qxf3 dxe5 \xskakcomment{guess?} 
6.Bc4 Nf6 \xskakcomment{guess?Hint: attacking Freddy pawn} 
7.Qb3 Qe7 \xskakcomment{guess?Hint: The other Knight joins in the attack} 
8.Nc3 c6 \xskakcomment{guess?}
9.Bg5 b5 \xskakcomment{guess?Hint: A sacrifice} 
10.Nxb5 cxb5 \xskakcomment{guess?} 
11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 \xskakcomment{guess?Hint: Short or Long} 
12.O-O-O Rd8 \xskakcomment{guess?Hint: Another sacrifice} 
13.Rxd7 Rxd7 \xskakcomment{guess?} 
14.Rd1 Qe6  \xskakcomment{guess?Hint: Sacrifice again}
15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 \xskakcomment{guess?Another sacrifice!!} 
16.Qb8+ Nxb8 \xskakcomment{What's the checkmate move?} 
17.Rd8#
}
\guessmymove
```

Comment: your document doesn't compile. game2.tex can not be found. And please shorten it to the  code relevant to for your question. All the decoration is certainly not needed to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo in your code and a number of unneeded or doublicated code. If you want side-by-side moves don't use multicol. I removed pstricks so that the document compiles with pdflatex. Load it only if you really need it and know what it is doing.

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=20]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[LSB2,LSBC4,T1]{fontenc} % use fontenc before chessboard
\usepackage{xskak}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}

\newcommand\guessmymove{% this is the 1st macro TO PRINT OUT ALL THE COMMENTS
    \xskakloop{%
    \ifcsempty{Xskak.\xskakgetgame{gameid}.\xskakget{movenr}.\xskakget{player}.nag}
    {}
    {%
    \getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}\raggedright
    \Large
    \chessboard[boardfontfamily=alphadia,
      boardfontencoding=LSBC4,
      normalboard, showmover=false, label=false, 
      pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=red,
      markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, 
      arrow=to,color=blue, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
      emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen},
      coloremph=true,
      whitefieldmaskcolor=yellow,blackfieldmaskcolor=yellow,emphfield=\xskakget{moveto},,
      setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
      \xskakget{opennr}
      \xskakget{lan}
      \xskakget{nag}
      \par
     \end{minipage}\quad 
      }}}

\xskakset{style=UF}


\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%********************* GUESS THE MOVE ***************************
\begin{center}
\setboardfontcolors{blackfieldmask=gray!40}
\newchessgame
\noindent
\hidemoves{
1.e4 e5  \xskakcomment{guess?}
2.Nf3 d6 \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Hint: attack the center }
3.d4 Bg4 \xskakcomment{guess?}
4.dxe5 Bxf3 \xskakcomment{guess?}
5.Qxf3 dxe5 \xskakcomment{guess?}
6.Bc4 Nf6 \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Hint: attacking Freddy pawn}
7.Qb3 Qe7 \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Hint: The other Knight joins in the attack}
8.Nc3 c6 \xskakcomment{guess?}
9.Bg5 b5 \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Hint: A sacrifice}
10.Nxb5 cxb5 \xskakcomment{guess?}
11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Hint: Short or Long}
12.O-O-O Rd8 \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Hint: Another sacrifice}
13.Rxd7 Rxd7 \xskakcomment{guess?}
14.Rd1 Qe6  \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Hint: Sacrifice again}
15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 \xskakcomment{guess?\\ Another sacrifice!!}
16.Qb8+ Nxb8 \xskakcomment{What's the checkmate move?}
17.Rd8#
}
\guessmymove
%this is the MACRO guessmymove
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]