# xskakloop printing out of moves - page 35

Tags: chess, xskak

In my previous post, [bigger font in labeling and diagram going side to side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496266/bigger-font-in-labeling-and-diagram-going-side-to-side), I left out the solution so this is a continuation.
I want to print out only the white moves. The code on page 35 is not clear about the moves. So I attempt to do it on my own. How can I change the font from the output. Can I do this for black as well? The manual's output has no listing of the moves. I attempt to do it but it shows me both the white and the black moves.

Thank you for your advice.

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=20]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{skak, xskak,chessboard}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\noindent
\hidemoves{
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Bg4 4.dxe5 Bxf3 5.Qxf3 dxe5 6.Bc4 Nf6 7.Qb3 Qe7 8.Nc3 c6 9.Bg5 b5 10.Nxb5 cxb5 11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 12.O-O-O Rd8 13.Rxd7 Rxd7 14.Rd1 Qe6 15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 16.Qb8+ Nxb8 17.Rd8#}
%*************** FROM PAGE 35 IN THE MANUAL *****************
\xskakset{%
moveid=\xskakgetgame{initmoveid},stepmoveid}
\whiledo{\xskaktestmoveid
{\xskakget{movenr}}{\xskakget{player}}}
{ \xskakget{lan}%
\xskakset{stepmoveid=2}}


%/*************** PRINT OUT ONLY WHITE MOVES IN A COLUMN
\xskakloop[step=2]{%
\begin{flushleft}
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\end{flushleft}\quad}%
\clearpage
%/*************** PRINT OUT ONLY BLACK MOVES IN A COLUMN
\xskakloop[step=1]{%
\begin{flushleft}
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\end{flushleft}\quad}%

\xskakset{%
moveid=\xskakgetgame{initmoveid},stepmoveid}
\whiledo{\xskaktestmoveid
{\xskakget{movenr}}{\xskakget{player}}}
{ \xskakget{lan}%
\xskakset{stepmoveid=2}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figure out how to print out the black moves differently than the manual. Below is my code.

I still don't know how to adjust the fonts.

```
%/*************** PRINT OUT ONLY BLACK MOVES IN A COLUMN
\xskakloop[initmoveid=1b,step=2]{%
\begin{flushleft}
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\end{flushleft}\quad}%
```

Comment: You change the fonts like always in LaTeX: by issuing in the right place commands like \large or \bfseries etc. I wouldn't bother with all this `flushleft` environments. A simple `\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}\par\smallskip` should work fine.